# Why is this deferred function not working?

Tags: jquery, timer, deferred

I created the following function as a sort of all purpose timer for a couple different functions:

```
function timer (time, d) {
    var state=d.state();
    if (typeof t === "undefined") {
      state="pending";
    };
    if (state === "pending") {
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        timer(time, d);
      }, time);
    } else {
      t = undefined;
      return d.promise();
    }
  }
```

I know it will never fail, because I never reject `d` anywhere.  This is meant to be used inside functions, so nothing will be global except `t`.  This seems fairly straight forward to me, and it was working before I added the check for `t`.  Why I did this is because I want the timer to run at least once no matter what.  But when I added the check for `t` in the beginning, the resolve handler doesn't fire.  I test with the following code:

```
var n=$.Deferred();
$.when(timer(2000,n))
 .done(function(p){
     console.log(p);
 });
 n.resolve('kittens');
```

Am I missing something?  "kittens" never gets logged.  Is there something with `setTimeout` I am not considering, or is it something else?  I haven't even entertained the possibility that this is an issue with jQuery - but it looks like it should work to me.

Comment: `timer` needs to always return a promise. But your code doesn't really make sense. Why poll a promise instead of listening for the done event? And even if this worked, the `n` is returned to the `$.when()` from `timer`, so the `console.log()` would happen as soon as `n` is resolved (that's the point of deferred objects). The `setTimeout` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to ever use `$.when()` when you only pass it a single promise.  Just use `timer().then()` and always return a  promise from `timer()`.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?  This seems very odd to be using a single global and essentially polling every 2 seconds.  I don't understand what behavior you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

The feature of `setTimeout()` that you're not considering is that its function argument is called from a future event turn. Therefore your `timer` function is not truly recursive.

> It has been debated elsewhere what this recursion-like behaviour should be called - I call it "extracursion" (where extra has the original Latin meaning of "outside").*

Anyways, the upshot is that :-

- if you pass an unresolved Deferred to `timer`, it is guaranteed to return `undefined` immediately. Meanwhile, the timer will merrily poll away "extracursively" until the Deferred is resolved, at which point the last call of `timer` will gleefully return its `d.promise()` into this air. *Nothing will ever receive the value returned from a function called with `setTimeout`.*
- the only way to make an initial call to `timer` return anything other than `undefined`, is to pass it an already resolved promise, in which case you might as well "cut out the middle-man" by writing :

```js
$.Deferred().resolve('kittens').then(function(k) {
    console.log(k); //kittens
});
```

or, more simply :

```
$.when('kittens').then(function(k) {
    console.log(k); //kittens
});
```

which is an over-elaborate way to achieve :

```
console.log('kittens');
```

In short, the whole `timer` exercise, as given, is completely pointless.

Comment: Your response seems to indicate that the only time to return a value is now...I don't actually want to log 'kittens'.  I'm trying to make synchronous functions work with asynchronous functions.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just having some fun at the end there, with various ways to log "kittens".

Comment: A function will always terminate in one of two ways; by returning or by throwing an uncaught error. Before it does one of those two things, it may have performed "side-effects". Recursion is a special kind of side-effect. Setting a timeout is another.

Comment: It was a good answer.  I got what I need.  But, why does it work when I don't check for a timer up front.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen the earlier version of the code.

Comment: Did you change something else when you added the `t` test? For example did you change `var state = d.state` to `var state = d.state()`? The first version (in the absence of the 't' test) would have the effect of sending execution to the `else` clause and a promise would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  Here's an all-purpose timer that uses promises.  It creates and returns and manages its own promise:

```
function timer(t, val) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(val);
    }, t);
    return d.promise();
}

timer(1000, "kitten").done(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hsv213xn/

As such, you can use it multiple times and in multiple places because it has no global state.

You don't need to use `$.when()` because it returns a promise which has it's own `.done()` so you can just call `.done()` on it.

And, here's a chained version of it:

```
function timer(t, val) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(val);
    }, t);
    return d.promise();
}

timer(1000, "kitten").then(function(val) {
    log(val);
    return timer(1000, "cat");
}).then(function(val) {
    log(val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/0142emh0/